# Power supply drop when connected to op amp

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

Today I was working with op amp (TL071),everything was fine,  I was able to generate a triangular signal going from 0 to ~15v 10khz using 4 op amp and a power supply (+15/ -15v) , after that I wanted to compare this signal to a DC voltage that varies between 1 and 14v with an op amp so I can generate a square signal , but when I connected my circuit (triangular signal to the +input , and the DC signal to the -input), the voltage of my power supply used for all my op amp (+15/-15)dropped to like 0.3v or something, knowing that it was perfectly working with the 4 previous op amp before connecting the fifth one, I don't know how to solve the problem .

Comment: Can you ask an answerable question? We also don't know what you connected and where and how so what if you made some error?

Comment: `I don't know how to solve the problem` is not a question ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: Give the schematic ... and what you wired.

Comment: Referring to the datasheet would be a good way to see what's going on. The amplifier is behaving exactly how it should. Frankly, the fact that you specifically say, "knowing that it was working perfectly.... [later] I don't know how to solve it" shows some extreme confirmation bias without questioning why "it worked".

Comment: Are you certain you didn't accidentally switch +15 and -15?